# Elasticsearch - query based on event frequency

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, event-tracking

I have multiple indexes to store user tracking log. In which there is 1 index is index-pageview. How can I query out the list of users who viewed the page 10 times between 2021-12-11 and 2021-12-13 using IOS operating system?

Log example:
index: index-pageview

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "session_id": "xxx",
    "timestamp": "2021-12-11 hh:mm:ss",
    "platform": "IOS"
}, 
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "session_id": "yyy",
    "timestamp": "2021-12-13 hh:mm:ss",
    "platform": "Android"
}
]
```

Comment: Please add your index mapping as well in question.

Comment: I use template index, no specific index. the schema of the event looks like above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building a normal `bool` query on `timestamp` and `platform` and then either `terms` aggregation (possibly with `min_doc_count: 10`) or `collapse` on `user_id`. Both ways will have some limitations though:

- aggregation might be slower (needs benchmarking)
- aggregation bucket number is limited (at 10k by default)
- collapse will work on at most `size` docs at a time (capped at 10k as well) so you might need scrolling and app-side processing

Though performance of these might be pretty poor. If you need to run queries like those very often I would consider using another storage (SQL? Something more fancy?)